# TYPO3 Custom content frame with id

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have added a range of custom frames defining them in the template setup like so:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  100 = TEXT
  100.value = <div class="myclass">|</div>
}
```

However this removes the content element id. How do I add the unique content element id back into the wrap like the default frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the uid of the element can be done like this:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject {
  100 = TEXT
  100.dataWrap = <div id="{field:uid}" class="myclass">|</div>
}
```

but basicaly, you overwrite the complete cObject by creating your own.
Take a look in the typoscript of css_styled_content to see how cTypes are rendered.

Comment: ``insertData`` is dangerous! Never use it for wraps, especially not on wraps around content inserted by an editor. It will also replace any ``{data:}`` statements inserted into the backend and give away information (e.g. db password). Use ``dataWrap`` instead.